# How do I create a box to hold text below Google maps within android?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, google-maps

At this point I know how to utilize Google Maps within Android but it always seems to take up the full window, there is an image below which shows what I'm attempting to accomplish (having a box below the Google maps where I can store text i.e. "Hello World"

**How do I add box below Google Maps, so to store text i.e. "Hello World"**

Code so far:

ActivityMain:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

Android xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Image: (Link to Image)
http://s28.postimg.org/j6xes5659/Google_Maps_Help.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android:layout_height` attribute in your `<fragment>` is set to `match_parent`, which means it will take all the available vertical space in its parent. There are several ways to accomplish what you want. For example, you can wrap the `<fragment>` and the desired text on a vertical `LinearLayout` and set some defined height for the fragment (i.e. `android:layout_height="200dp"`)

Comment: Could you please explain your solution further? I can understand that I need to alter the layout height but after that, I'm still at a loss.

Comment: Just try. Add something like a `Button` below the fragment in xml (use `android:layout_below="@id/map"` to place it below the fragment). At the beginning it will not show, but when you adjust the height it will.